# Restoring T-Log Backups at DR Site

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario where I'm shipping the T-Log backups to our DR site and restoring them to our DR SQL server.

The issue I'm trying to work out is that currently to do a test of the DR site we have to bring those databases on-line, do our test, and then ship over full backups so we can start the t-log restores.

Is there some way I could bring those databases live, do our tests, and get back to restoring mode database without having to ship over a full database backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres two ways I can think of to do what you want.

First method: Local recovery and rollback:

1. Stop the SQL service on the
   log-shipped instance.
2. Copy all the
   databases including the system
   databases to a safe spot - these are
   your roll-back files.
3. Bring the instance back online and recover
   your databases.
4. Once you are done,
       stop the instance and copy the
       roll-back files back back over the
       files and start back up and your
       log-shipping will resume.

   When copying the files used a copy
   utility to verify the files (copy /V
   etc) to ensure you're copies are viable.

Second method: Rename

1. Create a new database with the name you plan to use for your testing (this one will be overwritten at the file level with the copy of the log-shipped database).
2. Stop the SQL service on the
       log-shipped instance.
3. Delete the data and log file for the
   database created in step 1, make
   sure to track the file names for use
   in step 4.
4. Copy (duplicate) the database files
   for the log-shipped database to the
   same folders and rename them to match the DB files you just deleted in step 3.
5. Start the instance back up; The system will auto recover the database.
6. Drop the database when testing has completed.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot modify a database in standby, the very first write will diverge the database from its master and the whole process has to be re-seeded. One solution is to have your tests be non-destructive, ie. read only, so they can be run on the standby database.

Comment: What I meant was I would want to copy the databases off and attach them on a separate instance to do the test, while the original databases continue to be restored to during the test.